# Kotlin Class Extension

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I'm just learning Kotlin as a fun side-project for Project Euler.  I just started literally 5 minutes ago, in IntelliJ IDEA.

I have this code:

```
fun Number.isMultipleOf(n: Number): Boolean {
    return this % n == 0
}

fun main(args: Array<String>){
    println(10.isMultipleOf(5))
}
```

The compile error is this:

```
Kotlin: Unresolved reference.  None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
@Deprecated @InlineOnly public inline operator fun BigDecimal.mod(other: BigDecimal): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
```

I'm experienced in Java, Python, C++ and Swift so I figured Kotlin shouldn't be that much of a challenge.  But WTF is a "receiver type"?

How can I fix this compile error while getting the desired functionality out of the `Number` class extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just trying to explain the term receiver type and the error mentioned.

Error occurs in the line

```
return this % n == 0
```

If you look closely, `this` is of variable type **Number**. so **Number** is your receiver type in the statement above(as it receives second operand to operate). **Number** is the abstract super class for all Numeric objects like Int, Float ... in Kotlin, which does not have inline function to perform modulo(%) operation. Hence you are getting the error. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Oh!

Thinking for a minute, `isMultipleOf` wouldn't be that effective on floats and doubles due to floating-point precision issues.

So this is the modified code:

```
fun Int.isMultipleOf(n: Int): Boolean {
    return this % n == 0
}
```

And that compiles.